# Python Training dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, audio, scipy

I am trying to perform `music genre` classification. I want to use `MFCC` as a feature. I am using `scikit library` for that purpose. Here is my code simply:

```
> import numpy as np
> import scipy.io.wavfile 
> from scikits.talkbox.features import mfcc
> sr1,x1=scipy.io.wavfile.read("filename.wav")
> ceps1,mspec1,spec1=mfcc(x1)
```

I can obtain `MFCC` values as above. Now, I have 100 songs with 2 different music genres(`electronic`,`jazz`). And, I want to create a dataset with using these songs. I suppose I will use numpy arrays to design that dataset. How can I create that dataset and put them label(`electronic` or `jazz`)? I am using `python2.7` on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` built-in data-frame to upload names of the song files and give heading of columns as either *electronic* or *jazz.*

Here is high-level overview.

- Iterate through directory of song files and get file names.
- For each file get its corresponding MFCC value (Basically determine if it
  belongs to *electronic* or *jazz* category.
- For initial load to `pandas` data-frame , Create two separate list for *electronic* and *jazz*
- For subsequent load, you can append directly to respective columns in data-frame

Here is sample implementation which assumes you have obtained file-names, MFCC value and categorized the files for *electronic* or *jazz*

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['electronic','jazz']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=None, columns=columns)

elec_list = [ 'song1', 'song2', 'song3' ]
jazz_list = [ 'song5', 'song6', 'song7' ]


df = pd.DataFrame(index=None, columns=columns)
df['electronic'] = pd.Series(elec_list)
df['jazz'] = pd.Series(jazz_list)
```

**Output:**

> > df
> >            electronic   jazz
> >     0      song1        song5
> >     1      song2        song6
> >     2      song3        song7